# Contact form response appearing on the main page

Tags: php, html

I have a webpage with anchors and contact form is the last part. I have an echo message down there and as soon as I load the page it appears there. Any ideas how to make it appear it only when the mail is sent? Also, it autmatically send the mail if the page is loaded. Thanks.

Code for the form.

```
<form name="form1" id="ff" method="post" action="insert.php"> 
  <label>
    <span>Name*:</span>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Please enter your name" name="name" id="name" required>
  </label>

  <label>
    <span>Phone*:</span>
    <input type="tel" placeholder="Please enter your phone" name="phone" id="phone" required>
  </label>

  <label>
    <span>Email*:</span>
    <input type="email" placeholder="youremail@mail.com" name="email" id="email" required>
  </label>

  <label>
    <span>Message*:</span>
    <textarea rows="4" cols="55" name="comment" id="comment" placeholder="Purpose of contacting"></textarea>
  </label>

  <input class="sendButton" type="submit" name="Submit" value="Send">
  <?php 
  {
    if (isset($_POST['name'])) 
    // Get values from the form
    $name=$_POST['name'];
    $phone=$_POST['phone'];
    $email=$_POST['email'];
    $comment=$_POST['comment'];

    $to = "#";
    $subject = "New Mail From Website";
    $message = " Name: " . $name .  "\r\n Phone: " . $phone . "\r\n Email: " . $email . "\r\n Message: " . $comment;
    //$message = $comment;

    $from = "#";
    $headers = "From:" . $from . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n"; 

    if(@mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers,$email))
    {
      echo "<p class='contact-text'>Thank you for your email. I will contact you shortly!</p>";
    }else{
      echo "<p class='contact-text'>Error! Please try again.</p>";
    }
  } 
  ?>
</form>
```

Comment: Put php code outside the form and try.

Comment: doesn't "@" before "mail" suppress any error code?

Comment: @user2983295: no, it does: 'The lesson to take away from this is that the “@” operator suppresses error messages,' -> http://thesmithfam.org/blog/2006/05/07/php-the-operator/ ; Therefore, saying "@mail" means "send the email. If you don't, just don't care and go ahead".

Comment: @briosheje but how can it be than it works on my other projects, but not with this one? :/

Comment: @user2983295: there may be a ton of reasons for the mail() function not to work. Check this: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php and check if your php.ini is configured correctly :) Sometimes the "mailfrom" and some other things such as the ports needs to be set manually! Update: check this, for an example: http://www.quackit.com/php/tutorial/php_mail_configuration.cfm (please take care that such things usually depends on the web server you have installed, firewalls etc.)

Comment: @briosheje if I check the answer below it doesn't display the response anymore when I load the page, but now I doesn't display at all. Any ideas? quick note, if I put the php code into another file then it displays the message properly but thats not what I want.

Comment: @user2983295: try setting error reporting: `ini_set('display_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL);` and remove the "@" before "mail". Execute the script and check if any error is reported.

Comment: @briosheje no errors what so ever :/. Mail is sent an everything.

Comment: @user2983295: and it is not even saying that it actually sent it? you should really check the php.ini file if it still doesn't work.. If you want too, also, try using a library such as the PHP mailer: https://github.com/Synchro/PHPMailer perhaps using a mailer configured properly you won't have any issue. At this point, however, I'm really confident about the fact that the problem must be located into the ini file.

Comment: @briosheje but as soon as I move the php script to external file, it shows the "Mail sent, I will yada yada" message. So I don't know what can be the case. Also as soon as I changed the code to the code the answer someone posted below it doesn't show it anymore. Can you please check it out?

Comment: It doesn't work for me either.. I would suggest you to use PHPMailer, since it actually works for me using it, while I ckeck my php.ini :P

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
<?php 
  if (isset($_POST['name'])) {
    // Get values from the form
    $name=$_POST['name'];
    $phone=$_POST['phone'];
    $email=$_POST['email'];
    $comment=$_POST['comment'];

    $to = "#";
    $subject = "New Mail From Website";
    $message = " Name: " . $name .  "\r\n Phone: " . $phone . "\r\n Email: " . $email . "\r\n Message: " . $comment;
    //$message = $comment;

    $from = "#";
    $headers = "From:" . $from . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n"; 

    if(@mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers,$email))
    {
      echo "<p class='contact-text'>Thank you for your email. I will contact you shortly!</p>";
    }else{
      echo "<p class='contact-text'>Error! Please try again.</p>";
    }
  } 
?>
```

(It includes in the condition `if (isset($_POST['name']))` also the message)

Comment: Okay now the message is not display'd at all. Any ideas?

Comment: Try to remove the "@" and put at the top this code: error_reporting(E_ALL);

Comment: Then you could try to put </form> before the php code

Comment: Me too :( I'm sorry :/